Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/themecore/
hi everyone i need fix my problem magento 2.3.7 p4 add product to category i get this error in home page

after delete product from category the error fixing
but i need to add products to categories
the line 36
 <?php foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value): ?>

and all code in this page image_with_borders.phtml
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image */
/** @var $escaper \Magento\Framework\Escaper */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
/**
 * Enable lazy loading for images with borders and if variable enable_lazy_loading_for_images_without_borders
 * is enabled in view.xml. Otherwise small size images without borders may be distorted. So max-width is used for them
 * to prevent stretching and lazy loading does not work.
 */
$borders                         = (bool)$block->getVar('product_image_white_borders', 'Magento_Catalog');
$enableLazyLoadingWithoutBorders = (bool)$block->getVar(
    'enable_lazy_loading_for_images_without_borders',
    'Magento_Catalog'
);
$width                           = (int)$block->getWidth();
$paddingBottom                   = $block->getRatio() * 100;
$_config                         = $this->helper('Sm\Themecore\Helper\Data');
$enableLadyLoading               = $_config->getAdvanced('lazyload_group/enable_ladyloading');
$mediaSrc                        = $_config->getMediaUrl();
if ($enableLadyLoading) {
    $imgClass = 'lazyload';
} else {
    $imgClass = '';
}
?>
<span class="product-image-container product-image-container-<?= /* @noEscape */
$block->getProductId() ?>" style="width: <?php echo $width . "px"; ?>">
    <span class="product-image-wrapper">
        <img class="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getClass()) ?> <?php echo $imgClass; ?>"
            <?php foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value): ?>
                <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($name) ?>="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($value) ?>"
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php if ($enableLadyLoading) { ?>
            src="<?php echo $mediaSrc . 'lazyloading/blank.png'; ?>"
            data-src="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getImageUrl()) ?>"
        <?php } else { ?>
            src="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getImageUrl()) ?>"
        <?php } ?>
            loading="lazy"
            <?php if ($borders || $enableLazyLoadingWithoutBorders): ?>
                width="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>"
                height="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getHeight()) ?>"
            <?php else: ?>
                max-width="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>"
                max-height="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getHeight()) ?>"
            <?php endif; ?>
            alt="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getLabel()) ?>"/></span>
</span>
<?php
$styles = <<<STYLE
/**
.product-image-container-{$block->getProductId()} {
    width: {$width}px;
}
*/
.product-image-container-{$block->getProductId()} span.product-image-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: {$paddingBottom}%;
}
STYLE;
//In case a script was using "style" attributes of these elements
$script = <<<SCRIPT
prodImageContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".product-image-container-{$block->getProductId()}");
/**
for (var i = 0; i < prodImageContainers.length; i++) {
    prodImageContainers[i].style.width = "{$width}px";
}
*/
prodImageContainersWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(
    ".product-image-container-{$block->getProductId()}  span.product-image-wrapper"
);
for (var i = 0; i < prodImageContainersWrappers.length; i++) {
    prodImageContainersWrappers[i].style.paddingBottom = "{$paddingBottom}%";
}
SCRIPT;
?>
<?= /* @noEscape */
$secureRenderer->renderTag('style', [], $styles, false) ?>
<?= /* @noEscape */


<?php foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value): ?>
    <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($name) ?>="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($value) ?>"
<?php endforeach; ?>

Wrap the above code inside if condition as shown below
<?php if ($attributes = $block->getCustomAttributes()): ?>
    <?php foreach ($attributes as $name => $value): ?>
        <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($name) ?>="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($value) ?>"
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


Thank you mr @TarunBhalodia i have other error after fixed Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: secureRenderer in /home/user/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/themecore/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml on line 88

Actually you have not initialised the variable but you are using it, better you initialise the class \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer in block or viewmodel class whatever you are using and then use renderTag method on that object.
